# SCSS create a partial named generic class

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to have a partial named class like this

```css
.theme-color- {
  &yellow {
    color: yellow
  }
  &red {
    color: red
  }
  &blue {
    color: blue
  }
}
```

but a generic way like this

```css
$yellow = yellow;
$red = red;
$blue = blue;

.theme-color-#{$my-color} {
  color: #{$my-color};
}
```

```html
<div class="theme-color-red"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`@each`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each):

```
$colors: red, yellow, blue;

@each $color in $colors {
  .theme-color-#{$color} {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

This generates the following CSS:

```
.theme-color-red {
  color: red;
}

.theme-color-yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.theme-color-blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

---

You can also use `@each` with a map instead of a list if you want to specify custom color values:

```
$colors: (red: '#ff0000', yellow: '#fffd62', blue: '#0000ff');

@each $color, $hex in $colors {
  .theme-color-#{$color} {
    color: $hex;
  }
}
```

Which results in the following CSS:

```
.theme-color-red {
  color: "#ff0000";
}

.theme-color-yellow {
  color: "#fffd62";
}

.theme-color-blue {
  color: "#0000ff";
}
```

Comment: But if I don't want to have the generic yellow but one in hexa like `$yellow: #fffd62` ?